# Use null values in custom terraform provider as a new state

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider

I'm developing a new custom terrafrom provider using the terraform plugin framework. In the API, we have a nullable integer value (e.g. `someVar` can be an integer from 1 to 1000 or `null`). I've used this definiton for the `someVar` in the schema defintion:

```
"someVar": schema.Int64Attribute{
    Optional: true,
    Computed: true,
    Validators: []validator.Int64{
    int64validator.Between(1, 1000),
    },
},
```

In the `.tf` file i've used this:

```
someVar = 500
```

And later

```
someVar = null
```

The problem is the change to `null` for `someVar` is not being detected when using `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`.

I've tested `PlanModifier` (`ResourceWithModifyPlan`) to detect the `null` value but the problem is the result of `isNull()` for `someVar` is always false.

```
var plan myResourceModel
diags := req.Plan.Get(ctx, &plan)
resp.Diagnostics.Append(diags...)

if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
    return
}

// plan.someVar.isNull() -> false
```

What am I missing here?